# ASP:NET 411 - Content Length Required error

Tags: c#, asp.net

there are some questions and answers arround about the mean 411-error.
But mine is a bit strange: We have a Testserver and productive one. The error, I'm describing happens just on the testserver, which has exactly the same code as the produtive one (except the connection strings).
We're calling a WebMethod in Code behind:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static object GetEnterEditModeObject()
    {
        object btnId = HttpContext.Current.Session[Constants.Session.RoleEditBtnClientId.ToString()];
        var indRole = (V_WFA_ROLES)HttpContext.Current.Session[Constants.Session.RoleCurrentDatarow.ToString()];

        if (btnId != null && indRole != null)
        {
      ///... Some more code here

            var result = new
                {
                    btnId,
                    ///More Variables here

                };

            HttpContext.Current.Session[Constants.Session.RoleCurrentDatarow.ToString()] = null;
            HttpContext.Current.Session[Constants.Session.RoleEditBtnClientId.ToString()] = null;

            return result;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Nothing to fancy here: We read out two values from the Session, if they are there, we create a new object, clear the sessions and return the object, otherwise we just return null.

This worked fine for a long time, but now we get the error I mentioned above.
Since it is still working on production, I can fiddler it quite easy, and I get these two Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required
Date: Mon, 24 Feb 2014 13:10:40 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 344
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-UA-Compatible: IE=9; IE=8
Date: Mon, 24 Feb 2014 13:12:22 GMT
Content-Length: 10
Via: SomeURL
```

As you can see, the Content Length of both headers exist, but I still get this error.

Can you give me any hint, what could cause such a problem? Is there probably a error in the code behind, which can cause such harm? If yes, would a simple try/catch correct this problem?

Thanks for all responses and a good start in the week!

Matthias

Edit: Fixed it by adding

```
 [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

To all Webmethods, but now, I get the following

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Date: Mon, 24 Feb 2014 17:04:33 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 196
Location: /error_path/400.html?al_req_id=Uwt7oX8AAAEAAGijHI4AAAYG
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=500
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

It seems to move the page to an error_path, but it doesn't show any errors in Fiddler nor seem JavaScript to cause problems.

The behavior seems to be wanted, but as said the code is the same as in production, where this doesnt happen.

Are this IIS settings, which can cause my troubles?

Edith2: Got it, there was a new Firewall component install on the testsystem, which checked and changed the request-headers. So we learned: If the headers are different, there IS a difference on the system and the customer is wrong!

Comment: Matthias, could you please get in touch with me (email: mnot@mnot.net, or @mnot on twitter)? I'm researching an interoperability issue that seems to be lined to the firewall you mention. Thanks!